# ActionBar item is not showing when a ShapeDrawable is set as it's icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, shapedrawable

I am working on a simple project and I want to avoid the PNG images as much as possible. I need a '+' (Add) button and I created it using the ShapeDrawable with the given code.

res/drawable/plus_icon_drawable.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:color="#000"
                android:width="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke android:color="#000"
                    android:width="3dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This code works fine when I add it as a background of Button or an ImageButton but when I add this as an icon of an ActionBar item, the item is not getting displayed.

When I set a PNG image as the icon, it works fine. Is there any restriction for the ShapeDrawables which blocks it from getting rendered on ActionBar?

This is my ActiobBar code

res/menu/action_my_actions.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_some_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/plus_icon_drawable"
        android:title="My Action"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

**Update (08 July 2014):** Tested with both Native and AppCompat. Actually the item is present there but the ShapeDrawable image is not getting rendered. The action item responds to clicks.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I used that xml drawables too in a old ActionBarSherlock app. Which actionbar implementation do you use? Native? Compat? ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: @rekire Native, using support library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any restriction for the ShapeDrawables which blocks it from getting rendered on ActionBar?

Nothing like that. Its just how things are. Here's why you're seeing this:

`Layer/ShapeDrawables` don't have a default size. In other words, its perfectly fine for a `ShapeDrawable` to be of zero width and height. The stroke-width parameter does not dictate anything either.

> This code works fine when I add it as a background of Button or an ImageButton but when I add this as an icon of an ActionBar item, the item is not getting displayed.

Yes, of course. `ImageButtons/Buttons` have a concept of padding/ min-width/min-height. These allow the `ShapeDrawable` to have some room to breathe. For example, a Button styled with `Widget.Holo.Button` will have the `minWidth` and `minHeight` set:

```
<item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
<item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
```

A valid test here would be:

define an `ImageView` as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `ImageView` has no sizing guidelines in the definition above - we're using `wrap_content`. Nothing will be displayed. On the other hand, if you use a png drawable, it itself defines the size. In the example above, using a explicit size (say 50dp) will make the `ShapeDrawable` `visible`.

This is how `ActionMenuItemView` sets the drawable:

```
public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
    mIcon = icon;
    if (icon != null) {

        // Zero in case you don't define the <size /> 
        int width = icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int height = icon.getIntrinsicHeight();
        if (width > mMaxIconSize) {
            final float scale = (float) mMaxIconSize / width;
            width = mMaxIconSize;
            height *= scale;
        }
        if (height > mMaxIconSize) {
            final float scale = (float) mMaxIconSize / height;
            height = mMaxIconSize;
            width *= scale;
        }
        icon.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    setCompoundDrawables(icon, null, null, null);

    updateTextButtonVisibility();
}
```

Snippet from `ShapeDrawable#inflate(...)` method:

```
 setIntrinsicWidth((int)
            a.getDimension(com.android.internal.R.styleable.ShapeDrawable_width, 0f));
 setIntrinsicHeight((int)
            a.getDimension(com.android.internal.R.styleable.ShapeDrawable_height, 0f));
```

Without `ShapeDrawable_width` and `ShapeDrawable_height` defined, the intrinsic width and height will be set to zero. This means, the statement `icon.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);` (from setIcon(Drawable) method) is in fact => `icon.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);`.

So, it seems that we're indeed dealing with `ShapeDrawables` that don't have size info.

A possible fix:

```
<shape android:shape="line">
    <size android:width="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
          android:height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"/>
    <stroke android:color="#000"
            android:width="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

But this won't work - for some reason `?android:attr/actionBarSize` is not considered a dimension. This is odd because `?android:attr/actionBarSize` works fine when supplied to `android:layout_width` in case of layouts.

Workaround would be to define a new dimension, say `actionBarSizeDp` and set it up:

In `res/values/dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="actionBarSizeDp">48dp</dimen>
```

In `res/values-land/dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="actionBarSizeDp">40dp</dimen>
```

These values are the default action bar size values as defined in android's own res/values-XX/dimens.xml.

Finally, use `actionBarSizeDp` in `plus_icon_drawable.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <size android:width="@dimen/actionBarSizeDp"
                  android:height="@dimen/actionBarSizeDp"/>
            <stroke android:color="#000"
                    android:width="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90">
            <size android:width="@dimen/actionBarSizeDp"
                  android:height="@dimen/actionBarSizeDp"/>
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke android:color="#000"
                        android:width="3dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In fact, defining the `size` on one of the `LayerDrawables` should suffice. The other(s) will be drawn accordingly.

Comment: Bingo... That was amazingly helpful. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @gnuanu Yea, sorry about the long post though. I wanted to explain the issue instead of just posting a solution.

Comment: No problem at all. It was really interesting to learn the internals a bit.